# How do I bind a closure to a static class variable in PHP?

Tags: php, static, closures, bind

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $closure;

    public static function myFunc($input): string
    {
        $output = $input . ' is Number';
        return $output;
    }

    public static function closure(): Closure
    {
        return function ($input) {
            return self::myFunc($input);
        };
    }

    public static function run()
    {
        $closure = self::closure();
        echo $closure(1); // 1 is Number

        self::$closure = $closure;
        echo self::$closure(2); // Fatal error
    }
}

A::run();
```

I want to bind `self::closure()` to `self::$closure`, and use it internal, but it disappears somewhere.  How do I bind a closure to a static class variable in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Change your property to be static `static $closure;`
- Wrap your callable in brackets `(self::$closure)(2);`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d41490759cac39b8459e396b3acf99bf22c65a68

```
<?php

class A
{
    static $closure;

    public static function myFunc($input): string
    {
        $output = $input . ' is Number';
        return $output;
    }

    public static function closure(): Closure
    {
        return function ($input) {
            return self::myFunc($input);
        };
    }

    public static function run()
    {
        $closure = self::closure();
        echo $closure(1); // 1 is Number

        self::$closure = $closure;

        // Wrap your callable in brackets
        echo (self::$closure)(2); 
    }
}

A::run();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems:

Missing `static`:

`public static $closure;`

Missing parentheses:

`echo (self::$closure)(2);`

---

```
<?php

class A
{
    public static $closure;

    public static function myFunc($input): string
    {
        $output = $input . ' is Number';
        return $output;
    }

    public static function closure(): Closure
    {
        return function ($input) {
            return self::myFunc($input);
        };
    }

    public static function run()
    {
        $closure = self::closure();
        echo $closure(1); // 1 is Number

        self::$closure = $closure;
        echo (self::$closure)(2); // 2 is Number
    }
}

A::run();
```